# implement concurrecy in azure sync for ios app

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency, azure-mobile-services

How do we achieve concurrency with azure sync? If I want to do pull, push etc operations from a background ManagedObjectContext and read and display data from another main thread ManagedObjectContext?

Comment: did you read Azure offline sync feature? They have provided offline Sync feature. There are three way they have already mention in their documenations. Look at this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started-offline-data  and this one too https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/docs/mobile-services-ios-get-started-offline-data.md

Comment: @Gagan_iOS I am not using the offline sync feature. I am using sync just to download and maintain(update on each sync- in online mode always) the data on client device, I am using core data model. My issue is when I do a pull/push(sync) operation it blocks the UI most of the time.